# Show help-block after input box in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using *Twitter Bootstrap* with *jqBootstrapValidation* plugin to validate form input data.

When user enters does not enter data inside input box `<input type="email" name="email" required/>`  and tries to submit the form; the message "This is required field." appears below the input box. How can I make that message to appear after the input box (not on next line).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the container where the error is (in this case `p.help-block`), is `display: inline` or `float: right` and also has enough space after the input, if not, it is not going to work.

Notice that this also has some side effects like if you have a some kind of help text after your inputs, this change will move them next to the input too.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work, I also had to set the input itself to "display: inline" because it appears that inputs with class "form-control" use "display: block" by default.